# Affinity Propagation in R language

Tags: r

I am a student and I am using Affinity Propagation in my research. I installed `apcluster` packages in R. I want to do affinity propagation to NSL-KDD data set which is in CSV format. I uploaded the data set by using:

```
smp<- read.csv("F:/nsl1.csv", header=FALSE)
decision.table <- data.frame(smp)
View(smp)
```

Now I want to do AP for the data set.

I tried this command but it didn't help.

```
apcluster((s, smp, p=NA, q=NA, maxits=1000, convits=100, lam=0.9, 
          includeSim=TRUE, details=FALSE, nonoise=FALSE, seed=NA, ...))
```

Can you please help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't help"? Why do you have have double parenthesis `((`, `))`?

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are the following issues:

- The double parentheses are syntactically incorrect.
- What is 's'? You have to supply a similarity measure or a similarity matrix as argument 's'.
- You cannot pass an ellipsis argument '...' except from inside a function that also has such an ellipsis argument (for the purpose of passing on any other argument to apcluster()).
- You need not specify all parameters, only the ones for which you do not use the default.

My suggestion would be to start with the following simple variant:

```
apcluster(negDistMat(r=2), smp)
```

I had some look to the NSL-KDD data set and I think you will have to do a few more things to make apcluster work reasonably on these data:

- The data set seems to contain categorical columns. If you apply apcluster() as in the example above, apcluster() will omit all categorical columns (if they are factors in the data frame 'smp'). So you should first convert the categorical columns to numerical columns, e.g. by expanding each factor to as many binary columns as the column has different values ("levels" in R lingo).
- It seems to me that the data set is way too large to run standard AP. Standard AP computes a quadratic similarity matrix, so the limit that can be handled is something like 5,000 samples. If you have more, you have to take a sub-sample (which comes with the disadvantage that some smaller clusters may be lost) or use leveraged AP. The training set I saw on http://nsl.cs.unb.ca/NSL-KDD/ has ~125,000 samples which may be quite a challenge even for leveraged AP. So I'd suggest you start with a sub-sample to get some impression of how well AP works on this data set.

For more details, please see the package vignette.